# Ruby on Rails: Multiple Same Input Fields in Same Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Have a page where there are multiple input fields of the same thing, Posts. Right now, when a user enters in a question for, let's say 3 fields, the only one that saves to the database is the last one. Whereas, it should save all three and give them each it's own post_id. Also; if the user doesn't enter anything in for the other fields, it should not save in the database either.

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :content %>
  <%= f.text_field :content %>
  <%= f.text_field :content %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You want to create 3 unique posts out of one form?

Comment: chief - Yes, I think so. or should I create a new form for each? and display 3 forms on the same view page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's failing because what you've got above evaluates to thee html field with the *same name/id* and the browser will only post the value for one of them. If they are different fields, then you need to give them unique names/ids *or* you need to create them as an array eg:

```
  <%= f.text_field_tag 'content_array[]' %>
```

or, if you want these to be a *set* of posts - you'll need to add multiple sub-forms (one for each post) using a custom form.

Comment: I followed your suggestion for what I'm doing how can I display the views in my show.html. My show.html doesn't recognized 'content_array[]'

Comment: show me the code you have tried and the error message you got (edit your answer above and put it there).

Comment: A small correction. The browser does post all the different fields. However the rails params parser will use the value of the last name. You can check this by inspecting the `request.body` in your rails code.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is convert to html and as an array
in your form:

```html
<input`type="text" name="post[content][]" id="content_id">
```

Then, in your controller:

```
content_details = params[:post][:content]
content_details.each do|cont|
@post = Post.new(content: cont)
@post.save
```

This will loop through all of the content created and save each.