# Saving value with same input field in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model in rails called `info` with `address:string` and in my view I have the same input field that a user can enter a value into. Heres my form.html

```
<%= form_for(@info) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :address %>
  <%= f.text_field :address %>
<% end %>
```

I know it sounds weird not to add another additional field in the info table, but I'm trying hard just to use address column alone. I'm trying to display both the values in the show but only the last one is displayed, my guess that the first address is not saved but the last one is always saved instead of both.

My show html

```
<p>
  <strong>Addresses:</strong>
  <%= @info.address %>
</p>
```

How can I save both values into the table from the two input fields and display them both in my show. html? If anyone can provide a way or a solution I would be thankful.

UPDATE

```
def create
   address_array = params[:info][:address]
   address_string = address_array[0] + ', ' + address_array[1]
   params[:info][:address] = address_string

    respond_to do |format|
      if @info.save
        format.html { redirect_to @info, notice: 'Info was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, info: @info }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @info.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to create two separate address fields altogether, you can pass the same `address` argument to each of two tag helpers *as an array*:

```
<%= f.text_field_tag 'address[]' %>
<%= f.text_field_tag 'address[]' %>
```

Then, in your controller, you can access the respective values of each of the two fields as members of an array:

```
address_array = params[:address]
address_string = address_array[0] + ', ' + address_array[1] # Assigns comma delimited string
```

Thereafter, you can pass `address_string` as the value for the `address` attribute of your model.

If you don't want to change your model schema, there's considerable upside to this approach since you can use your `address` attribute as-is – all you're doing is modifying how the field is treated in the form, and then processing the return values in your controller accordingly.

**UPDATE**:

The `params` hash can be modified in-place such that `params[:info][:address]` reflects your custom string, rather than an array of two string:

```
def create
    address_array = params[:address]
    address_string = address_array[0] + ', ' + address_array[1]
    params[:info][:address] = address_string # Assigns `address_string` to `params[:info][:address]`
    # remainder of the `create` logic
end
```

**UPDATE 2**:

Your `new` and `create` controller actions should look something akin to this:

```
def new
   @info = Info.new
end

def create
   address_array = params[:address]
   address_string = address_array[0] + ', ' + address_array[1]
   params[:info][:address] = address_string

  respond_to do |format|
    # First, instantiate a new instance of `Info`
    @info = Info.new(params[:info])
    # Then, save
    if @info.save
      format.html { redirect_to @info, notice: 'Info was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, info: @info }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @info.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

**UPDATE 3**:

If you're having issues modifying the `params` hash in place, you may want to try assigning the `address` attribute directly:

```
def create
   address_array = params[:address]
   address_string = address_array[0] + ', ' + address_array[1]

  respond_to do |format|
    @info = Info.new(params[:info])
    @info.address = address_string # Assign attribute directly
    if @info.save
    # remainder of code
```

Comment: what method do I adjust in my controller set_info, or info_params

Comment: @CalvinJones, see my update for details on how to modify your `params` hash in place. Once you've done so, you can pass the value to your new object instance as you would normally.

Comment: thank you so much for the help. Now I'm getting undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass on the first line of the create method. I'm pretty new to rails

Comment: Have you changed your `form_for` fields to `f.text_field_tag 'address[]'`?

Comment: It was already generated when I scaffold Info address:string and views were already made along with the controller and models

Comment: Copy my controller code _precisely_, including the `new` action. Then, make sure that you're passing `@info`, rather than `:info`, to your `form_for` helper. This should be more than sufficient detail to get things working for you.

Comment: Ok it's giving me that same error we must be running on different versions of rails but thank you so much for the help got a idea of what to do next sort of

Comment: One final update: try accessing `params[:address]`, rather than `params[:info][:address]`... that should make things work – does it? I've updated my answer to reflect.

Comment: if I take that out like you suggested the error moves to line 3 now because of params[:info][:address]. It's something about params[:info][:address] that it doesn't like. Then if I take [:info] out in the 3rd line like the first line. It runs fine with no error but nothing is saved both address input are blank. Thanks for trying, I'll look at it more and try to solve it

Comment: One more idea: try assigning the `address` attribute directly. I've depicted this in my third update to the answer. If this fails, something else is amiss – I'm guessing it might be an issue with your model declaration.

Comment: That was it wow! Thank you so much for your assists God bless you and your family for everything you've done. Learned a lot this last 6 hours working on this. Thank you again and God bless you for your kindness and help

Comment: it was very very helpful, and yes I did upvote to your post only wish I could could give more upvote

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<%= form_for :info do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :address1 %>
    <%= f.text_field :address2 %>
<% end %>
```

Then in your controller:

```
def create
    # Look up model object

    address = "#{params[:info][:address1]} #{params[:info][:address2]}"

    # save model object with address
  end
```

The basic idea is to create the form without using the attributes on your model, then in the controller pull the needed info out of the `params` hash and make the column data yourself.

Comment: in the view you have address1 and address2, I'm guessing you can't just use address for both input fields. I saw http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556888/ruby-on-rails-multiple-same-input-fields-in-same-form this one which is very similar but don't know what content_array is or how to display it

Comment: There are several different ways to do this, no matter what though you're going to have to manipulate the data somewhere. Using a separate column in your database really is the easiest approach. Is there a reason you want to combine them?

Comment: no reason I just want to display both values in my show somehow using one column thanks for the input and help dude

Comment: Of course man. Rails works really hard to make things easy for you, for stuff like this its best not to fight it :)

Comment: @DanFairaizl, I'm not convinced this approach works. When the `form_for` helper accepts a model instance as an argument, it reconciles the attributes on the model with the fields being generated. Since `address1` and `address2` aren't attributes – and they're presumably not being generated on the fly – this approach will likely throw an exception.

Comment: @zeantsio, notice I am not passing a model instance to `form_for`, just a symbol. It can be anything this was just an example to get OP going in the right direction.