# How to permit array of strong parameter value with form fields RAILS 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I have an invitation system where there is an email field that people can add new user emails to.

currently this accepts 1 email, I would like to allow the user the ability to dynamically add new additional email fields, so when it submits, I have an array of email address allowed in by rails strong param

here is the view template

```
<%= form_for @invite, :url => landlord_property_invites_path(@landlord.id,@property.id) do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email ,class: "form-control"%>
    </div>
    <span class="btn btn-default btn-addon">Add another tenant</span>
    <%= f.submit 'Send Email',class:"btn btn-success" %>
<% end %>
```

here is my invite params

```
  private
  def invite_params
    params.require(:invite).permit(:email)
  end
```

So what I want to do, is when they click `add another tenant`

then the form will look like this

```
<%= form_for @invite, :url => landlord_property_invites_path(@landlord.id,@property.id) do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email ,class: "form-control"%>
    </div>     
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email ,class: "form-control"%>
    </div>
    <span class="btn btn-default btn-addon">Add another tenant</span>
    <%= f.submit 'Send Email',class:"btn btn-success" %>
<% end %>
```

so basically the `:email` param will map to an array of all the fields in the form like so,

```
:email = {useremail@gmail.com, useremail2@gmail.com}
```

then I can do things indivially in a `for each` loop in my controller

Currently the params accepts whatever the last value is in the email field and disregard the rest

i have tried

```
    params.require(:invite).permit(email:[]) and
    params.require(:invite).permit(:email => [])
```

but it still does the same thing.

So how would i do allow params to accept the hash of value coming in??

Comment: You cannot use the form helper that way. When you tell ruby "f.email_field :email", rails will look for the active record attribute called email. f is @invite in this instance. So you're saying "@invite.email = <form_result>".

Comment: well yea, I think so, 

i am saying, is email gets all of the value of :email in the form, what otherway can i do it?

Comment: I think you can  use form helpers with fields_for  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#using-form-helpers

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out,

this is what I would put in my view template

```
    <%= email_field_tag 'email[]' %>
    <%= email_field_tag 'email[]' %>
```

it has to be a tag without the f. object

I allow it through with

```
  def invite_params
   params.permit(email:[])
 end
```

and access it with this

```
    @emails = invite_params['email']
```

this would give me

```
@email = ['email1@gmail.com,email2@gmail.com']
```

here is the link i used

[Saving value with same input field in form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22162221/saving-value-with-same-input-field-in-form?lq=1)